# When I push to git I have get error that name of component is toolong

Tags: git, gitlab

My question is about... hello, I have a C# project with angular app and there I have my external module
I am trying just `git add .` And I have got error that filename is too long, after that I delete this file and I got same error/ What is it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the actual error you're getting and reformat your question (you've repeated it twice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this git config --system core.longpaths true